# How to evaluate the ratio of (large) gamma functions in the normal inverse gamma marginal likelihood?

Tags: bayesian, computational-statistics, inverse-gamma-distribution

I am doing some Bayesian modeling where I am using Normal-Inverse-Gamma as prior for the unknown mean and variance, and Normal for likelihood. In my application, I need the marginal likelihood, where mean and variance are integrated out, for some downstream analysis.

From Murphy page 17 (https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Papers/bayesGauss.pdf), the marginal likelihood contains the term:
$$\Gamma(a_o+n/2)/\Gamma(a_o)$$
where $a_o$ is the first parameter of the Inverse-Gamma prior, and $n$ is the number of samples.

My question is, how is this ratio evaluated in practice when you have hundreds of data points without numerical overflow? As far as I can see, even a moderate $n$ will shoot the gamma function to infinity. I tried to search online and found an approximation:
$$\Gamma(a+n)/\Gamma(a)=a^n$$
But still, in my case, any hyperparameter $a_o$ larger than 1 and a moderate sized sample will make this to infinity.

This should be a fairly simple problem for know-how computational statistician, but I am very new to this, so any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: You'd normally evaluate its logarithm. Presumably at some later point you'll presumably be dividing by a number of broadly similar order of magnitude?.

Comment: Besides using log-transforms, setting aside such constant terms should be feasible since they only depend on the sample size $n$. It is only when one need compare models that they should be included.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried to use log-transform and on Matlab it seems that $log(\Gamma(n)) = \inf$ for $n \sim 200$ or larger. I am actually building a binary tree where each leaf is a gaussian (hence each leaf has a gamma function ratio). The probability of each tree is product of leaves (hence product of gamma function ratio). When I compare trees, I use MCMC, which could give something like $$\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)/\Gamma(c)\Gamma(d)$$ where a, b, c, d are potentially large, is there a way to simplify this when using Matlab to evaluate? Because Matlab gives NaN if I do (inf * inf)/(inf * inf).

Comment: @coolestBro Don’t take the log of gamma, use gammaln instead: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gammaln.html

Comment: @hejseb worked like a charm! Thank you!